# Cannot search for External ID

Tags: custom-object, externalid

I have created a custom object in my Salesforce Org, I have created a new field in this org with 'External ID' selected.

I presumed that I am able to search via that field in the global search bar in Saleforce however I have tried but no results are shown even though there should be records in the object that match the search string.

Why is this?

**EDIT:**
Here is the actual record data and the search query reults.
[image: Proof of VLAN record]
[image: Search results]

Comment: Could you possible give an example of a failing search scenario and/or the volume and style of custom object records you are dealing with? (i.e. if you have an external ID on a text field and have loaded 500,00 records this morning, they may still be being indexed!)

Comment: The object consists of an ID, VlanNo, IP. An example record would have the following data `ID-0001, Vlan101, 1.1.1.1`. The VlanNo is the External ID (and is case insensitive). I have only just created this object in my sandbox and there are only 3 records inside it. WHen searching for 'Vlan101' nothing is found.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your "Search Options" settings?

Comment: Updated @PepeFloyd

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong, you need to create a tab to be able to search for an object from Global Search. Do you have a tab for this object?

Comment: I do not have tab for this object, it is merely used as a related list. If it is because there is no tab, could I create a tab but by default have it hidden?

Comment: Yes, you can set the tab as "Default Off", if you set it to hidden it won't work.

Comment: I have created a tab and set it to 'Default Off', however I still cannot see the records I am searching for.